# How to I edit the select lines with the arrow keys command in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2, keyboard-shortcuts, selection, sublimetext

I'm trying to find out what the setting is for the way Sublime Text handles code selection with the keyboard.

Example:

- Hold Command + Shift + < or > to highlight a line
- Next if you then click up or down, it will select everything above or below

Ideally I'd like to just continue selecting lines up or down, line by line rather then the whole thing.

Anyone know how to edit that feature?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CMD + L` selects the cursor's line.

Then `SHIFT + UP / DOWN` adds the previous / next line to the selection.

Comment: Ah thanks! I noticed there was another way to do this too, but I had to turn off the default shortcuts for mission control(which I never use) Shift+Cntrl+ ^ or v will make multiple cursors

Comment: For me shift + cntrl + ^ or v swaps the current line with the line above/below it. Which is odd because I remember I used to be able to select multiple lines. Also, I've noticed some functionality is different on my laptop vs desktop due to shortcuts pre-programmed for Windows.